# Bootstrap table - recargar registros segun objeto ajax json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, bootstrap

Estoy creando una página web con **Bootstrap**. Inicialmente al cargar la página utilizo **PHP** para insertar los resultados en las celdas de la tabla. Hasta aquí todo bien.

Después utilizo un botón con un menú modal de **Bootstrap** el cual tiene una serie de campos que se indican para posteriormente al clicar en ejecutar llamé a través de **JQuery**, **Ajax**, a una página **PHP** mediante envío *POST* de 4 parámetros.

Esta consulta me devuelve un objeto **Json** que incluyo en una `array` de **JavaScript** pero que no soy capaz de que mi tabla me muestre esos datos.

Realmente he probado casi de todo pero se me debe estar pasando algo.

Se que el objeto **Json** me devuelve un `array` tal que así:

```js
{
  "estado":"PE",
  "id_usuario":"20",
  "nombre":"Irene",
  "apellido1":"Munn\u00e9",
  "id_addtime_horario":"7",
  "fecha":"2016-12-30",
  "dia_semana":"friday   ",
  "hora_ini":"10:00:00",
  "hora_fin":"15:09:26",
  "jornada":"05:42:12",
  "jornada_flexibilidad":"00:02:46",
  "jornada_deficit":"00:00:00",
  "extra_jornada":"00:00:00",
  "extra_autorizado":null,
  "id_fichaje":"1766",
  "id_fichaje_detalle":"44071"
}
```

Y hasta donde yo sé, que no es mucho, se enlaza por **JavaScript** de la siguiente manera:

```
  $('#executaquery').on('click', function(){

          //  Recupero valors per POST to php

          var usuari = document.getElementById('usuari').value;
          var estat = document.getElementById('estat').value;
          var data_in = document.getElementById('data_in').value;
          var data_fi = document.getElementById('data_fi').value;

          $.ajax({                                                              // Llamada a queryProduct.php devuelve objeto array JSON asigno a
             method: 'POST',                                                      // los campos de modal window
             dataType: 'json',
             url: 'queryFitxatges.php',
             data: { usuaris: usuari, estats: estat, datain: data_in, datafi: data_fi},

             success: function(response) {

                $('#consulta').modal('hide');

                var myData = [];
                myData.push(response);

                $('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('load', myData);
             }
          });
      });
```

Os he pasado todo el código que utilizo para enviar los parámetros de la consulta y me devuelva el objeto json. La línea de código que enlaza los datos con la tabla es:

**$('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('load', myData);**

Por último por los ejemplos que he podido ver en la documentación oficial se enlazaría directamente con la instrucción anterior y la definición de los campos del objeto json idénticos a los data-field de la table. Que también lo tengo así:

```
      <table class='table-bordered' id='tableprod'
      data-toggle='table'
      data-toolbar='#toolbar'
      data-sort-name='name'
      data-sort-order='desc'
      data-pagination='true'>

      <thead class='thead-inverse'>
          <tr>
              <th data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>
              <th data-field='estado' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[0]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='id_usuario' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[1]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='nombre' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[2]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='apellido1' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[3]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='id_addtime_horario' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[4]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='fecha' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[5]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='dia_semana' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[6]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='hora_ini' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[7]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='hora_fin' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[8]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='jornada' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[9]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='jornada_flexibilidad' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[10]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='jornada_deficit' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[11]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='extra_jornada' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[12]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='extra_autoritzado' data-sortable='true'><?php echo $cols[13]; ?></th>
              <th data-field='edit' data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>EDIT</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <?php while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
          <tr id='<?php echo $row[14]; ?>' data-idfixatgedetall='<?php echo $row[15]; ?>' data-estado='<?php echo $row[0] ?>' data-autoritzat='<?php echo $autoritzat = $row[12]; ?>'>
              <td></td>
              <td data-field='estado'><?php echo $estado = EstadoIcon($row[0]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='id_usuario'><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
              <td data-field='nombre'><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
              <td data-field='apellido1'><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
              <td data-field='id_addtime_horario'><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
              <td data-field='fecha'><?php echo $date = FormatDate($row[5]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='dia_semana'><?php echo $dia = Dia($row[6]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='hora_ini'><?php echo $time = FormatTime24($row[7]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='hora_fin'><?php echo $time = FormatTime24($row[8]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='jornada'><?php echo $time = FormatTime($row[9]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='jornada_flexibilidad'><?php echo $time = FormatTime($row[10]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='jornada_deficit'><?php echo $time = FormatTime($row[11]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='extra_jornada'><?php echo $time = FormatTime($row[12]); ?></td>
              <td data-field='extra_autoritzat'><?php echo $autoritzat = Autoritzat($row[13]); ?></td>
              <td><button class='btn btn-xs edit btn-addcom' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">edit</i> </button></td>
          </tr>
    <?php }  ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

He probado hacer lo mismo a la mínima expresión sin pasar parámetros, haciendo una tabla nueva... pero no hay manera.

A ver si me podéis echar una mano a entender la teoría y poder solucionar mi problema.

Mientras tanto seguiré buscando...

Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo lo hagas con angular. Al hacer la llamada ajax desde angular y retornar el json. Pones $scope.datos=recibe; y listo. Echale un vistazo

Comment: Voy a ver, gracias @Alexis Granja por el consejo

Answer (score 1):

Deberias realizar algunas pruebas de que devuelve. O sea, verificar si recibes un JSON o un string y debes parsearlo.

Lo que veo es que estas mezclando un poco de `jQuery` con un poco de `javascript`+`DOM`. Pero creo que el problema lo tienes con el `array push` que obtienes del PHP.

Pasé a limpio como me parece que debería ser...

```
 $('#executaquery').on('click', function(){
          var usuari = $('#usuari').val();
          var estat = $('#estat').val();
          var data_in = $('#data_in').val();
          var data_fi = $('#data_fi').val();

       $.post('queryFitxatges.php',{ 'usuaris': usuari, 'estats': estat, 'datain': data_in, 'datafi': data_fi},function(response){
                if (typeof(response) == "string"){response= JSON.parse(response);) 
                $('#consulta').modal('hide');                
                $('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('load', response);           
       })
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema son estas dos líneas dentro del `success`:

```
var myData = [];
myData.push(response);
```

Lo que ocurre es que `myData` es un **arreglo** de objetos, y al hacer el `push` con la respuesta del servidor, lo que estás generando es un arreglo que en primera posición tiene **otro arreglo** que es la respuesta de tu servidor, básicamente:

```
[      // Empieza la posición 0 de myData
  [
    {    // Empieza la posición 0 de la respuesta
      "estado":"PE",
      "id_usuario":"20",
      "nombre":"Irene",
       ...
    },   // Termina la posisión 0 de la respuesta
    {    // Empieza la posición 1 de la respuesta
      "estado":"PE",
      "id_usuario":"21",
      "nombre":"Juan",
       ...
    }    // Termina la posisión 1 de la respuesta
  ]   // Termina la posición 0 de myData
]
```

Lo único que tienes que hacer es omitir dichas líneas y repoblar la tabla así:

```
$('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('load', response);
```

Entonces el código de tu llamada AJAX debería quedar así:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'queryFitxatges.php',
    data: { usuaris: usuari, estats: estat, datain: data_in, datafi: data_fi},
    success: function(response) {
               $('#consulta').modal('hide');
               $('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('load', response);
             }
});
```